# EmberJS Handling Complex Object returned from REST Api

Tags: rest, ember.js, laravel, handlebars.js

I have the following `user` object returned from a REST Api:

```
{
    user: {
        id: 3451,
        name: "First Last",
        favorites: {
            designs: {
                name: "Design 1",
                url: "Url 1"
            },
            typo: {
                name: "Typo 1",
                url: "Url 2"
            },
            games: {
                name: "Game 1",
                url: "Url 3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got this response from the url `/users/3451`.

And here's my `User` model:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    favorites: DS.attr(), // ??? What to put here?
});
```

I have no problem displaying the `{{name}}`. But in the `favorites`, I don't know.
I tried using `{{#each}}`

```
{{#each favorites}}
    {{@key}} - {{name}}
{{/each}}
```

but no luck.It throws an error: `Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed [object Object]`

What is the correct way of handling these kinds of complex objects in EmberJS? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error is pretty self explanatory: you need to be looping over an array, not an object. Here's how I would convert that object to an array, while saving the key (put this in your model):

```
favoritesArray: function() {
    var favorites = this.get('favorites');
    return Em.keys(favorites).map(function(key) {
        return {
            key: key,
            data: favorites[key]
        };
    });
}.property('favorites.@each.{name,url}')
```

Then, in your template:

```
{{#each favoritesArray}}
    {{key}} - {{data.name}}
{{/each}}
```

That would be the easiest way to do it. But if you're looking for a slightly better way (in my opinion), you can user a [type transform](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Transform.html) to convert the data to the format you need at the time of (de)serialization.

EDIT: Just for a bit of background info, I believe the reason that Ember.js doesn't support iterating over objects is because there is no way to bind to the object keys. Ember.js knows to update a bound helper when the dependent key observers are fired, but as far as I know, there is no way to observe the keys of an object. Something like this might be possible using an `Map` or similar, but I don't think that it's built in functionality.